Is there a canonical parametrization of a map $f\in \mathrm{Lip}(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^d)$ like the arc-length parametrization?
It is known that given a $C^1$ curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^d$ we can always find a reparametrization $\tilde\gamma$ so that $\dot{\tilde{\gamma}}=1$ given $\dot\gamma\neq 0$.
This can be pushed forward more to Lipschitz curve given the derivative is far from zero.
My question is if it is possible to achieve something similar for parametrised surfaces or more.
Given $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\mathrm{rk}(Jf)=k$ everywhere, is it possible to find a reparametrisation $g:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^k$ to make it so $\det (J(f\circ g)^t.J(f\circ g))\equiv 1$?
The problem is finding a function $g\in C^1(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^k)$ such that
$$
1=\det [J(f\circ g)^t.J(f\circ g)]=\det[Jg^t.Jf^t(g).Jf(g).Jg]=\det(Jg)^2\det(Jf^t(g).Jf(g))
$$
and so we get the PDE
$$
\det(Jg)=\sqrt{\det(Jf^t(g).Jf(g))},
$$
where we disregard the sign change without loss of generality.
The equation seems mild enough to admit solutions but I cannot wrap my head around it.
Trying to change variables continuously for each component using the arc-length for each of them doesn't produce good results as it gives a change of variables differentiable in one direction bu continuous in the others.
I have found that normal coordinates intuitively should be the thing to solve this problem but I am unfamiliar with the literature an so I don't know how far this can be pushed.
So from my understanding if $f\in C^\infty$ then I can view this as a parametrization of a manifold and can find local coordinates given by the exponential function.
Maybe they are even global because the manifold is the graph of a function.
What I do not know is if this can be pushed for $f\in C^1$ because things in differential geometry tend to break down below $C^2$, and if that is possible what I would like to know is if this can be pushed even to $f\in \mathrm{Lip}(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^d)$.
If this is classical then just a reference or a nudge would be greatly appreciated.

This is indeed classical. The answer is no, and is yes only when the Riemann curvature tensor is zero. A proof is given by Riemann, if I understand correctly.

@ArcticChar and can I have a reference please?

Forget my last comment: I forgot about the $\det$ in your equation.
